# Value object with "specified" flag

Tags: c#, .net, class-design, nullable

I need to pass values to a method, along with an indication of whether each value is specified or unspecified, since *null* is a valid value itself, and therefore cannot be interpreted as "unspecified".

I took the generic approach and created a simple container for such values (see below), but is this the right way to go? Are there better ways to approach this problem - e.g. does a class like this already exist in the framework?

```
public struct Omissible<T>
{
  public readonly T Value;
  public readonly bool IsSpecified;
  public static readonly Omissible<T> Unspecified;

  public Omissible(T value)
  {
    this.Value = value;
    this.IsSpecified = true;
  }
}
```

The method signature could look like the following, allowing the caller to indicate that certain values shouldn't be updated (unspecified), others should be set to null/another value (specified).

```
public void BulkUpdate(int[] itemIds, 
  Omissible<int?> value1, Omissible<string> value2) // etc.
```

Comment: Do you mean for your second constructor to take a `T` parameter and do nothing with it?

Comment: Looks right for me. I would suggest you to use a `struct` instead of a `class`. Also check the second `constructor`, the `value` parameter is not being used.

Comment: Whoops, corrected. Struct also a good idea.

Comment: I wonder about the semantic meaning of "not specified" but yet containing a value...

Comment: @lc. Me too. Perhaps setting *Value* to `default(T)` when *isSpecified == false* would be better.

Comment: I would also override GetHashCode, ToString and Equals (like NullableT does)

Comment: Strike that, I've removed the second constructor, and added the "Unspecified" static field as an alternative.

Comment: `Omissible<int?>` is pretty odd - is it useful to know that you've got an `int?` value, but its value is the null value? You've got two levels of "optionality" which sounds like it's a recipe for confusion.

Comment: @JonSkeet - it is useful to know whether the nullable int value is specified as `null` or not specified at all (i.e. should not be taken into consideration).

Comment: I would even consider making properties instead of fields, throwing from `Value` if `IsSpecified` is false, and setting `IsSpecified` to true when you set `Value`.

Comment: @JonSkeet - but I tend to agree with you. That's why I felt the need to ask the question. In this case `null` is just a value like any other, and I *needed* the extra optionality. With reference types it seems slightly less confusing: `Omissible<MyEntity>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best one can theoretically do. In order to distinguish a general `T` from a "`T` or `null`" you need one possible state more than a variable of type `T` can hold.

For example, a 32 bit int can hold `2^32` states. If you want to save a `null` value in addition you need `2^32 + 1` possible states which does not fit into a 4 byte location.

So you need a `bool` value in addition. (Theoretically speaking you just need `log2(2^32 + 1) - 32` bits for the `Omissible<int>` case, but an easy way to store this is a `bool`).

Comment: He needs *two* control values apparently, `null` and *unspecified*.  Which might call for a `byte` and an `int`.